# Cash outs, are they always in cash or are there other options?

Tags: casino

This question is about cash outs in brick-and-mortar casinos or poker clubs.
Assuming your cash out is in tens of thousands or more, Do you always cash out in cash or will casinos pay by check or wire transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casinos in Nevada will cash out with checks with large amounts, I do not know about wire transfers, but I believe some do. Talk to a casino host or inquire at the casino cage.